# Create MS Teams team in C# - AddAsync returns null

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

**Context:**

I am creating new MS Teams team using MS Graph API in C#

**My code:**

```
var newTeam = new Team()
{
    DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
    Description = model.Description,
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["template@odata.bind"] = $"{graph.BaseUrl}/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        ["members"] = owners.ToArray()
    }
};

var team = await graph.Teams.Request().AddAsync(newTeam);
```

**Problem:**

The team is created fine but I can't get it's id. Return type of `AddAsync` method is `Task<Team>` but it always returns null.
I have checked server response using Fiddler and found out that the id of created team is returned in response headers.

> Content-Location: /teams('cbf27e30-658b-4021-a8c6-4002b9adaf41')

Unfortunately I don't know how to access this information.

Comment: This endpoint should return the created team with its Id.
Are you using v1.0 or Beta SDK? and which version?

Comment: It should but it doesn't. I am using v.1.0 API. SDK version 3.19

Comment: FYI having the same issue, on 4.6

Comment: try this AddResponseAsync api to create the team, you can get location value from its response header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily this is quite easy to achieve by using the requests base class `BaseRequest` and sending it yourself. With the received `HttpResponseMessage` you get the headers as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-2) which contains the id of your new team.

The code also includes how to wait for the team creation to finish using a busy wait – which is not considered as best practice, but makes the sample easier. A better approach would be to store the team id and periodically query the creation status.

```cs
var newTeam = new Team()
{
    DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
    Description = model.Description,
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["template@odata.bind"] = $"{graph.BaseUrl}/teamsTemplates('standard')",
        ["members"] = owners.ToArray()
    }
};

// we cannot use 'await client.Teams.Request().AddAsync(newTeam)'
// as we do NOT get the team ID back (object is always null) :(
BaseRequest request = (BaseRequest)graph.Teams.Request();
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

string location;
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await request.SendRequestAsync(newTeam, CancellationToken.None))
    location = response.Headers.Location.ToString();

// looks like: /teams('7070b1fd-1f14-4a06-8617-254724d63cde')/operations('c7c34e52-7ebf-4038-b306-f5af2d9891ac')
// but is documented as: /teams/7070b1fd-1f14-4a06-8617-254724d63cde/operations/c7c34e52-7ebf-4038-b306-f5af2d9891ac
// -> this split supports both of them
string[] locationParts = location.Split(new[] { '\'', '/', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string teamId = locationParts[1];
string operationId = locationParts[3];

// before querying the first time we must wait some secs, else we get a 404
int delayInMilliseconds = 5_000;
while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(delayInMilliseconds);

    // lets see how far the teams creation process is
    TeamsAsyncOperation operation = await graph.Teams[teamId].Operations[operationId].Request().GetAsync();
    if (operation.Status == TeamsAsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
        break;

    if (operation.Status == TeamsAsyncOperationStatus.Failed)
        throw new Exception($"Failed to create team '{newTeam.DisplayName}': {operation.Error.Message} ({operation.Error.Code})");

    // according to the docs, we should wait > 30 secs between calls
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperation?view=graph-rest-1.0
    delayInMilliseconds = 30_000;
}

// finally, do something with your team...
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get your teamId by calling the GET [joined Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example), it will get the team id ,name and description

Comment: I am adding a team with application permissions so I don't have "logged user" context, so I can't use **joined Teams** approach. But even if I have user context this approach won't return the created team. It returns all teams that current user is "in".

Comment: Currently Joined Teams will give list of teams that you have joined, we need to search by the Team name to get the id from the list.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is struggeling to get this done in Graph SDK version 5.x, this is what worked for us:

```
var nativeResponseHandler = new NativeResponseHandler();
var createTeamRequestInformation = applicationClient.Teams.ToPostRequestInformation(team);
createTeamRequestInformation.SetResponseHandler(nativeResponseHandler);

await applicationClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(createTeamRequestInformation, TeamCreatedEventMessageDetail.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
using var responseMessage = nativeResponseHandler.Value as HttpResponseMessage;
var location = responseMessage.Headers.Location.ToString();

var locationParts = location.Split(new[] { '\'', '/', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var teamId = locationParts[1];
var operationId = locationParts[3];
```

inspired by this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75721864