# How to access response header in Graph v5.0 SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

While I'm trying to upgrade to the [Graph SDK to v5.0](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) I'm running into an issue  when upgrading the password reset of a user. According to the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethod-resetpassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you can send a user defined password like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0/authentication/passwordMethods/28c10230-6103-485e-b985-444c60001490/resetPassword
Content-type: application/json

{
    "newPassword": "Cuyo5459"
}
```

Unfortunately this call is currently not supported within the SDK and we have to manually build the request and send it:

```
var requestInfo = serviceClient.Users[userId].Authentication.PasswordMethods[passwordMethod.Id].ToGetRequestInformation();
requestInfo.HttpMethod = Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Method.POST;
requestInfo.URI = new Uri(requestInfo.URI, "/resetPassword");
requestInfo.Content = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{\"newPassword\":\"{password}\"}}"));
```

The problem arises when it comes to read the response. According to the documenation you'll get an empty body and the header contains a location URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-type: application/json
Location: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0/authentication/operations/88e7560c-9ebf-435c-8089-c3998ac1ec51?aadgdc=DUB02P&aadgsu=ssprprod-a

{}
```

But if we send the request by ourself through the request adapter of the graph service client, we can't access the response header:

```
var passwordResult = await serviceClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(requestInfo, PasswordResetResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

According to the [Kiota documenation](https://microsoft.github.io/kiota/extending/kiotaabstractions.html#response-handler) it should be possible to register an `IResponseHandler` and that could probably access this information, but I can't find anything about how to register such an handler for a single specific request in the graph service client. Also in the documentation you can provide through the `errorMapping` parameter special serializers depending on the response status code, but even this would be just a `ParsableFactory<>` that can only access the body and not the header of the response (if I understood it correctly).

So what approach can be taken by using the v5 Graph SDK to access the response header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking into the [`AsyncMonitor<T>` code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/AsyncMonitor.cs) we can see, that a [`NativeResponseHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-abstractions-dotnet/blob/main/src/NativeResponseHandler.cs) can be used when performing raw request information:

```
var requestInformation = new RequestInformation() { HttpMethod = Method.GET , UrlTemplate = this.monitorUrl};
var nativeResponseHandler = new NativeResponseHandler();
requestInformation.SetResponseHandler(nativeResponseHandler);
await this.client.RequestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(requestInformation, cancellationToken:cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
using var responseMessage = nativeResponseHandler.Value as HttpResponseMessage;
```

In my given code example it would look like this:

```
var nativeResponseHandler = new NativeResponseHandler();
var requestInfo = serviceClient.Users[userInformations.UserPrincipalName].Authentication.PasswordMethods[passwordMethod.Id].ToGetRequestInformation();
requestInfo.HttpMethod = Method.POST;
requestInfo.URI = new Uri(requestInfo.URI, "/resetPassword");
requestInfo.Content = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{\"newPassword\":\"{password}\"}}"));
requestInfo.SetResponseHandler(nativeResponseHandler);

var passwordResult = await serviceClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(requestInfo, PasswordResetResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
using var responseMessage = nativeResponseHandler.Value as HttpResponseMessage;
var location = responseMessage.Headers.Location;
```

To use this stuff within the graph client, when the desired method is available but you need to additionally access the response header, you could do this with code similar to:

```
var nativeResponseHandler = new NativeResponseHandler();
await service.Drives[drive.Id].Items[sourceItem.Id].Copy.PostAsync(new CopyPostRequestBody
{
    Name = sourceItem.Name,
    ParentReference = reference,
},
config => config.Options.Add(new ResponseHandlerOption { ResponseHandler = nativeResponseHandler }));

using var responseMessage = nativeResponseHandler.Value as HttpResponseMessage;
var location = responseMessage.Headers.Location;
```

The information about how to add the `ResponseHandlerOption` has been added to the [v5 upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#native-response-object).